# Can you restrict Spring Boot API to prevent more than one of the same query parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

This may be a weird request, but I am working on a Spring Boot API and there is a requirement that, if someone sends the same query parameter more than once, that it throw a 400 error. But, because Spring Boot automatically pulls in the parameters as a delimited list, I am not sure how to do this.

For example, if someone sends `/my-api?foo=some%20stuff&foo=some%20more%20stuff` then the resulting value for foo is "some stuff, some more stuff". But I am supposed to be throwing an error message in this instance.

I cannot find any documentation on how to validate this. I suppose that I could examine the request before it reaches the controller and do some work on it there. But I was hoping that there was some config or annotation that I could use.

Comment: Why _before_ it reaches the controller? Do it _in_ the controller, it's trivial to check whether you got an array of multiple values.

Comment: Not if the parameter IS an array

Comment: The problem is not receiving an array of items. The problem is that the client used the same parameter multiple times.

Comment: The same query parameter being repeated is a _representation_ of an array. If the parameter is supposed to be an array why is that a problem?

Comment: Because that is the requirement... Believe me, I have gone rounds about this. It is not my decision. Just my job to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

There's no purely declarative way, but there's a simple code way:

```
@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters
```

Then the first line of the controller method:

```
if (parameters.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v.size() > 1)) {
    // throw 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to use a [ServletFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter).

A servlet filter is a piece of code that is executed before and after every request and that can perform extra tasks on it.

Typical uses of ServletFilters are:

- Logging HTTP requests
- Preventing SQL Injection
- Detecting patterns of misuse
- Limiting rate of servce (e.g. max 100 requests/s)
- many other uses

The cool thing about ServletFilters is that you write the code in a single place, and then you decide which URLs it applies to.

Moreover, a URL can be serviced by multiple filters. In this case they are processed in a nested way.

Comment: Thanks. That was kind of what I was referring to with "I suppose that I could examine the request before it reaches the controller and do some work on it there". I was just trying to see if this was the easiest solution, or if there was some sort of annotation/config items that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrangle the raw query string.  You can get the raw query by accepting an HttpServletRequest parameter:

```
@GetMapping
EntityResponse getSomething(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
  String query = servletRequest.getQueryString();
  // do something with query string
  ...
}
```